# Example where $\text{rk}(\tau^2)=\text{rk}(\tau)$ but $\text{im}(\tau)\cap\ker(\tau)\neq \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Question 9 of Chapter 2 of Advance Linear Algebra by Roman is as follows:

Let $\tau \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $\dim(V)< \infty$. If $\text{rk}(\tau^2)=\text{rk}(\tau)$ show that $\text{im}(\tau)\cap\ker(\tau)=\{0\}$.

I think I know the proof.

Suppose $\dim(V)=n$, then $n-\dim(\ker(\tau^2))=n-\dim(\ker(\tau))$ and so $\dim(ker(\tau^2))=dim(\ker(\tau))$. Moreover, $\ker(\tau) \subset \ker(\tau^2)$. Hence, $\ker(\tau^2)=\ker(\tau)$, which implies $$\tau^2v=0\rightarrow\tau v=0\ \ \forall v\in V.$$
Now if $x=\tau v \in \text{im}(\tau)\cap\ker(\tau)$, then $\tau^2v=0$, which implies $x=0$, and the proof is completed.

The reason we need the finiteness of dimension is to conclude $\dim(\ker(\tau^2))=\dim(\ker(\tau))$ from $\text{rk}(\tau^2)=\text{rk}(\tau)$.

Now, would you give me a counterexample example in infinite dimensional vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the space of polynomials with real coefficients. This is clearly an infinite dimensional vector space over the reals. Let $T$ be the differentiation operator. $T$ is of course surjective so $\text{Im}(T)=\text{Im}(T^2)$ but it's not injective, so $\text{Im}(t)\cap \ker(T) \neq \{0\}$.